# Creating a Macro in Excel 2007 to extract moving data

Tags: vba

I have one sheet which is comprised of data that was imported from a web page. In a second sheet I have a cell asking for min price and max price which comes from the imported data. The issue is that the data can move to different cells when it's refreshed so my code needs to look for some specific wording to find the prices that I need rather than just directing it to the same cell each time

The info in the imported data sheet which I need to extract from will always be in this string of text which will always be found somewhere between row 15-35 but will move when the website is refreshed. The 1st number (71.00) needs to be extracted to another sheet in a cell asking for min price while the second number (75.00) is the max price. These prices can change so I can just look for those numbers and extract them.

SLAUGHTER BULLS: Yield grade 1-2 1000-1500 lbs 
1500-2000 lbs 71.00-75.00.

Could someone please help me with the coding for this macro?

Comment: Is that text all in the same cell, or split across different cells?

Answer (score 0):

Use the InStrRev function (similar to the LastIndexOf function in .NET) to find the last index of "lbs" in the test string.

```
lastIndex = InStrRev(testString, "lbs", 1, 1)
```

Then search from that last index to the end of the string spliting on the -

```
splitArray = Split(Mid(testString, lastIndex, Len(testString) - lastIndex), "-", 1)
```

The lowest value will be in splitArray(0) and the upper value will be in splitArray(1) assuming a zero indexed array.

Comment: Thank you is that how I would type the entire coding? I've never done VBA before so I'm not familiar with the formatting or exactly how to type the commands

Comment: That will get the values into the splitArray, and then you would need to set the value of the cell you want the numbers in to that variable.  Something like `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = splitArray(0)` to put the value into cell A1 on the active sheet.